# Imagen en modal botbox.js en js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo un código donde se crea un bloque y dentro de este mismo se crea la imagen tomada de una url. En la siguiente parte es donde creo mi imagen. Todos estos contenidos se meten en un objeto `OBJETOS ={}`. Vi unos ejemplos donde usaban `target._OBJETOS.URLImagen`; traté de esta manera y no sé si lo hago equivocadamente, recibiendo de parámetro en la función (target).

```
bloque += '<div id="originalImgRDR" style="display:none" align="center"><img src="' + target._infoObj.URLImage + '"title="" alt="" class="imgRdr" onload="hideSkeletonImgRDR()" onclick="divHideShow()" onerror="showErrorLoadImg()"/></div>';
```

En mi método  `onclick` llamo a siguiente función:

```
function divHideShow(id, path, fecha, desc) { 
 bootbox.dialog({
  /*title : '',*/
  message: '<div class="form-group col-md-12"><div class="form-group col-md-4"><span>Periodo: </span>'+id+' </div> <div class="form-group col-md-8"><span>Descripci&oacute;n: </span>'+desc+'</div></div> <div class="form-group col-md-12" id="div_'+id+'" style="display:block"><img id="img_'+id+'" src="'+path+'" title="" alt="" class="img-responsive" /></div>',
  backdrop:true,
  buttons : {
   success : {
    label : "Aceptar",
    className : "btn-primary principal",
   }
  }
 });
}
```

Los parámetros de el `div` solo son ejemplos de otra clase.